# How to POST login information to API Gateway to GET object from Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get authentication with Cognito working for an Amazon S3 static website.

I've made a login page in a separate bucket that has a form for entering the username/password. Once this is submitted, it authenticates using Cognito and, if successful, sends a POST request to API Gateway with the resulting token in the authorization header.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$(function onDocReady() {
    $('#signinForm').submit(handleSignin);
});

function handleSignin(event) {
    var username = $('#usernameInputSignin').val();
    var password = $('#passwordInputSignin').val();
    event.preventDefault();
    signin(username, password,
        function signinSuccess(result) {
            console.log('Successfully Logged In');
            token = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            alert('access token: ' + token);
            sendToken(token);
        },
        function signinError(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    );
}

function sendToken(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _config.api.invokeUrl,
        headers: {
            Authorization: token
        },
        success: function(res){
            alert('It worked!');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error stack: ' + (new Error()).stack);
        }
     });
}
```

My API Gateway is set up as an S3 proxy, so the resources are the bucket and file name for my S3 webpage. The bucketname/filename resource accepts the POST request and is configured with a Cognito authorizer to check the token. The POST method is associated with an integration request that should send a GET request to S3 to grab the webpage.

However, when I test this out, I keep getting a `405 Method Not Allowed` for the POST request. I thought this was a CORS problem at first, but I've configured API Gateway to work with that so I don't think that's the problem.

Here's what is displayed in the network console (I edited out some things to try to shorten it):

```
General:
Request URL: [login-page-URL]
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Response Headers:
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 422
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 17:29:31 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

Request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: [my-token]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: [login-page-URL]
Origin: [login-page-URL]
Referer: [login-page-URL]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

So to me, it looks like the source of the request for my S3 webpage comes from my login page. Shouldn't it be coming from the API Gateway?

And why does a POST to the API Gateway lead to a POST request for the S3 webpage? How can I make a POST to my API Gateway lead to a GET from S3 to get my static webpage? If I set up the integration request for my POST request to send a GET request to my S3 webpage, shouldn't that work?

I'm very unfamiliar with JavaScript and API Gateway, so I'm not sure if it's a problem with my code, or the API Gateway configuration, or both. I appreciate the help!

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of what I've got configured on API Gateway:
[image: API Gateway configuration]

I also have GET methods in there for the resources, to test that the API Gateway was working (and those worked fine).

Comment: Is your API Gateway's Resource set up with a POST method?

Comment: Yes, and I've added a picture of how my API Gateway is configured.

Comment: I don't see that AWS disallows what you're trying to do, but if you match your http method type to your Method execution http method type, does it still give you 405?

Comment: Tried that and it seems to help, but now I'm getting a 401 UnauthorizedException for the GET to the URL (the deployed API URL + the bucket and object names)

Comment: That indicates to me that there's an issue with the way you're handling the cognito auth. You have your own authorizer or are you using the built in API Gateway one?

Comment: I'm using a Cognito authorizer

Comment: I mean, are you doing that through API Gateway, under the Method Request, or another way?

Comment: I have the GET method use the Cognito user pool authorizer under Method Request in API Gateway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172024/discussion-between-ryan-gibbs-and-syim).

Comment: You need to use the getIdToken() instead of accessToken.